# Doubt in Bolzano- Weierstrass theorem

Tags: real-analysis

$ Theorem $

There are two statements i know

1) In R<sup>k</sup> ,every bounded sequence contains a convergent subsequence

2) Every bounded infinite subset of R<sup>k</sup> has a limit point in R<sup>k</sup>

$Doubt 1$

How to prove these two statements are equivalent?

$   Proof of Statement 1$

Suppose that { p<sub>n</sub> } be a bounded sequence in R<sup>k</sup> . 
Let P = { p<sub>n</sub> :  n $\in$ N } is bounded . Since$ \overline{P} $ is a closed and bounded subset of R<sup>k</sup> , by Heine-Borel Theorem , $ \overline{P} $ is compact . Because { p<sub>n</sub> } is a sequence in $ \overline{P} $ a compact subset of a metric space , there exists a subsequence of { p<sub>n</sub> } that is convergent in $ \overline{P} $.

$Doubt 2$

How can we prove that $ \overline{P} $ is bounded ?

Comment: For your second question: do you know how to prove that the closure of a bounded set is bounded? That's all that's going on there.

Comment: The closure is the original set unioned with its limit points. Since the original set is bounded, the only worry would arise from the limit points somehow being arbitrarily large; but, if limit points are arbitrarily large, then there are elements of the original set arbitrarily close to them, which would mean elements that're arbitrarily large, too. And this cannot be the case since the original set is bounded.

Comment: You cannot proof these statements are equivalent because they aren't. Take e.g the alternating sequence defined by $$x_n = (-1)^n$$ then 1) states the existence of a converging subsequence while 2) cannot be used because $$\{-1,1\} \subset \Bbb R$$ is not an infinite subset.
So 1) and 2) cannot be equivalent.